# How do I organize and structure multi-sub/function VBA code such that it actually runs?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I setup a run/macro to execute the below code. I've tried many things, including creating a new module that only calls each of the subs individually -- no luck. The output for this project should be an excel workbook that contains  worksheets (4 rows x 8 columns) with parsed JSON text in each cell. The worksheets correspond to unique URLs. For example, Sheet1 = URL1 data, Sheet2 = URL2 data, etc.

```
Option Explicit

Function GetJson(ByVal url As String) As Dictionary

With New WinHttpRequest
    .Open "GET", "URL" ''[Should this be a random URL, my list of URLs?] 
    .Send
    Set GetJson = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.ResponseText)
End With

End Function

Sub FillTaxiInfo(data As Dictionary, sheet As Worksheet)
Dim i As Integer, taxi As Dictionary
For i = 0 To UBound(data("prices")) - 1
    Set taxi = data("prices")(i)
    If taxi.Exists("ViewDisplayName") Then
      sheet.Cells(i, 1) = taxi("ViewDisplayName")
      sheet.Cells(i, 2) = taxi("fare")("fareType")
Next i

End Sub

Sub FillMultipleCityInfo(myUrls As Variant, book As Workbook)

Dim i As Integer, data As Dictionary, sheet As Worksheet

For i = 0 To UBound(myUrls) - 1
    Set data = GetJson(myUrls(i))
    Set sheet = book.Sheets(i + 1)
    FillTaxiInfo data, sheet
Next i
End Sub

 Dim myUrls As Variant
myUrls = Array("URL1", "URL2", "URL3", "URL4", "URL5", "URL6", "URL7")
FillMultipleCityInfo myUrls, ActiveWorkbook
```

Comment: Why is myUrls defined as Variant? If I were a compiler, I'd think that myUrls is an array of Strings...

Comment: Is there a sub at the bottom? as currently that piece of code is not inside a `Function or `Sub` thus will not work.

Comment: @dragonsamu I'm working off a suggestion -- so I never was clear on how that would run just sitting at the bottom. Its an integral piece, because it allows me to cycle through my URL list. How do you suggest I update?

Answer (score 2):

Move the global variable to the top, then make an entry point sub that initializes it and executes `FillMultipleCityInfo`:

```
Option Explicit

Dim myUrls As Variant

Public Sub RunThis()
    myUrls = Array("URL1", "URL2", "URL3", "URL4", "URL5", "URL6", "URL7")
    FillMultipleCityInfo myUrls, ActiveWorkbook
End Sub

Function GetJson(ByVal url As String) As Dictionary
    With New WinHttpRequest
        .Open "GET", "URL" ''[Should this be a random URL, my list of URLs?]
        .Send
        Set GetJson = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.ResponseText)
    End With
End Function

Sub FillTaxiInfo(data As Dictionary, sheet As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Integer, taxi As Dictionary
    For i = 0 To UBound(data("prices")) - 1
        Set taxi = data("prices")(i)
        If taxi.Exists("ViewDisplayName") Then
          sheet.Cells(i, 1) = taxi("ViewDisplayName")
          sheet.Cells(i, 2) = taxi("fare")("fareType")
        End If 
    Next i
End Sub

Sub FillMultipleCityInfo(myUrls As Variant, book As Workbook)
    Dim i As Integer, data As Dictionary, sheet As Worksheet

    For i = 0 To UBound(myUrls) - 1
        Set data = GetJson(myUrls(i))
        Set sheet = book.Sheets(i + 1)
        FillTaxiInfo data, sheet
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: "Compile error: Next without For" error under the sub `FillTaxiInfo`. Not sure why... seems there are both...? Also, under `GetJson` I initially tried `.Open "GET", myUrls(i)` but it did not allow the variable `myUrls(i)` which I believe I need to cycle through my URLs, no?

Comment: @Kyle - There was a missing `End If` in your code that I missed.  See edit.

Comment: thanks. Now getting a "type mismatch" error on `For i = 0 To UBound(data("prices")) - 1` under `FillTaxiInfo`

Comment: @Kyle - I have no clue what `data("prices")` contains, but that error would indicate that it isn't an array.